# Should large amounts of data go in the app state in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Let's say I have some data tables, like a list an admin report returning a list of users (with details) or a list of log records.  Does this info belong in the redux store, where only the data table needs this info?  Or what if I am plotting something with 5000 nodes.  Does this belong in redux single app state too?  Why or why not?

If these items do not belong in the app state, is it just the local component state I should be loading these into without redux?  Seems nice to have all my async requests fetched similarly, though.

Answer (score 1):

Since redux doesn't care about the data (it literally just calls reducer functions when actions are dispatched, and replaces the current state with the result), there shouldn't be any performance issue there. It will be as performant as the reducer functions you provide.

If you'd like to see for this directly: https://github.com/rackt/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L115

You're more likely to run into performance issues with react, but even then its doubtful at that scale. You may want to virtualize your table so that you're not rendering out of view elements, but that's a common problem with ui programming.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Redux way is to put all your client-side state in the Redux store. See the [Three Principles of Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html), the first one in particular:

> **Single source of truth**
>
> *The state of your whole application is stored in an object tree within a single store.*
>
> This makes it easy to create universal apps, as the state from your server can be serialized and hydrated into the client with no extra coding effort. A single state tree also makes it easier to debug or introspect an application; it also enables you to persist your app’s state in development, for a faster development cycle. Some functionality which has been traditionally difficult to implement - Undo/Redo, for example - can suddenly become trivial to implement, if all of your state is stored in a single tree.